# Derivation of expectation of random variable with delayed differential equation

Tags: lebesgue-integral, expected-value, change-of-variable, delay-differential-equations

I have problem deriving the expectation of random variable from a delayed differential equation. Any comment or advice for getting the result would be much appreciated!

The distribution of random variable $q \in [0, \infty]$ satifies

$$qf(q) = A [F(q)-F(q-B)]$$

where $F(q)$ is CDF, $f(q)$ is PDF and $A$ and $B$ are some constants.

If we integrate both sides over the domain, we get

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} qf(q) dq &=  A \int_0^{\infty}  [F(q)-F(q-B)] dq \\
&=A \left[\int_0^{\infty} [F(q)-1] dq + \int_0^{\infty} [1-F(q-B)] dq\right]\\
&=A \left[-\int_0^{\infty} qf(q) dq + \int_0^{\infty} [1-F(q-B)] dq\right] \\
\int_0^{\infty} qf(q) dq &= \frac{A}{1+A} \left[\int_0^{\infty} [1-F(q-B)] dq\right]
\end{align}$$
Then changing of variable $x = q-B$, we have $q = x+B$ and $dq = dx$. So
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} qf(q) dq &= \frac{A}{1+A} \left[\int_{-B}^{\infty} [1-F(x)] dx\right]
\end{align}$$
The answer says that as $F(X)=0$ for $x\leq 0$, then
$$\begin{align}
\int_0^{\infty} qf(q) dq &= AB
\end{align}$$
But I am so confused. I was thinking the following derivation:
$$\begin{align}
\int_{-B}^{\infty} [1-F(x)] dx &= \int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F(x)] dx + \int_{-B}^{0} 1 dx \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} [1-F(x)] dx + B \\
&=\int_{0}^{\infty} x f(x) dx + B 
\end{align}$$
And this is where I am. Is this right and how can I get the answer?

Answer (score 2):

What you've done so far looks good to me, and you're almost there!  If you put $\ E=\int_\limits{0}^\infty qf(q)\,dq\ $, the expectation you're trying to calculate, then your equations
$$
\int_\limits{0}^\infty qf(q)\,dq= \frac{A}{1+A} \left[\int_{-B}^{\infty} [1-F(x)] dx\right]
$$
and
$$
\int_{-B}^{\infty} [1-F(x)] dx=\int_{0}^{\infty} x f(x) dx + B 
$$
give you
$$
E=\frac{A}{1+A}[E+B]\ .
$$
I'm sure you're capable of solving this for $\ E\ $.